# Sending email with attached .ods File

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-mailer

```
send_mail('Subject here', 'Here is the message.', 'selva@gmail.com', ['stab@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False)
mail = send_mail('Subject here', 'Here is the message.', 'selvakumaremmy@gmail.com', ['vsolvstab@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False)
mail.attach('AP_MODULE_bugs.ods','AP_MODULE_bugs.ods','application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet')
mail.send()
```

I'm using Django send_mail class for sending mail. Here I want to send mail with attachment, my attachment File (.ods) is in local storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [EmailMessage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/email/#django.core.mail.EmailMessage)

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage

email = EmailMessage(
    'Hello',
    'Body goes here',
    'from@example.com',
    ['to1@example.com', 'to2@example.com'],
    ['bcc@example.com'],
    reply_to=['another@example.com'],
    headers={'Message-ID': 'foo'},
```

)

```
mail.attach('AP_MODULE_bugs.ods',mimetype='application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet')
```

mail.send()

> attach() creates a new file attachment and adds it to the message. There are two ways to call attach():

- You can pass it a single argument that is an email.MIMEBase.MIMEBase
  instance. This will be inserted directly into the resulting message.
- Alternatively, you can pass attach() three arguments: filename,
  content and mimetype. filename is the name of the file attachment as
  it will appear in the email, content is the data that will be
  contained inside the attachment and mimetype is the optional MIME
  type for the attachment. If you omit mimetype, the MIME content type
  will be guessed from the filename of the attachment.

  Eg: message.attach('design.png', img_data, 'image/png')

Comment: Thanks @selvakumar

Answer (score 1):

try using `attach_file()`

**Ex:**

```
mail = EmailMessage('Subject here', 'Here is the message.', 'selva@gmail.com',  ['stab@gmail.com'])
mail.attach_file('PATH TO AP_MODULE_bugs.ods', mimetype='application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet')
mail.send()
```

Comment: return exception "object has no attribute 'attach_file"

Comment: Updated snippet.